# PHP Woocommerce get product brand name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I create plugin and want to get brand name from woocommerce.
In fist time i post product no.1 the plugin it's work and get product brand as i wish but when i create product post no.2 and no.3 from brand name get from product no.1

whats wrong ?

```
if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
        $kode = $product->get_sku();
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'brand', array('orderby'=>'name'));

        $brands = get_terms( 'brand', array(
        'orderby'       => 'name'
        //,'product__in'  => $product->id
        // orderby arguments ('name', 'slug','term_group', 'term_id', 'id', 'description')
        ) );

        foreach ( $brands as $key => $brand ) :
            $brand_name = $brand->name;
        endforeach;

        $merk = $brand_name;

        //this i want to print the brand name
        echo "<strong>STOCK ".$merk." ".$kode."</strong><br/>";


    } else {
      echo "please active your WooCommerce plugin.";
    }
```

Comment: Can you post more code so we can see what you are doing with it. `$brand_name` will be set to the last value in `brands`.

Comment: i have been edit the code, please check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work for you.

```
if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
        $kode = $product->get_sku();

        $tax = array(
        'STOCK'=>'brand',
         );

        foreach ($tax as $mk_label => $mk_value) {
            $make_array = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), $mk_value, array("fields" => "names"));
            foreach ($make_array as $value) {
                $mk .= $value.", ";
            }
            echo '<strong>'.$mk_label.' <a href="javascript:void(0)">'.rtrim($mk,", ").' '.$kode.'</a></strong>';
            $mk ="";
        }


    } else {
      echo "please active your WooCommerce plugin.";
    }
```

We are taking terms dynamically based on current product id and fetching the brand accordingly. Let me know if you need any more help.

Thanks

Comment: Pleasure is all mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want get terms from product, you should try this:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'brand', array('orderby'=>'name'));
//you could use: var_dump($terms); to see what it is.
```

If you want to concat your brand names, you could do this:

```
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'brand', array('orderby'=>'name', 'fields' => 'names'));
$term_names = implode(' ', $term_names);
echo $term_names;
```

Comment: not working, can u spesific ? the value is array, i can't see

Comment: @Hengky ST use var_dump($terms) to see.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

```
foreach ( $brands as $key => $brand ) :
    echo "<strong>STOCK ".$brand->name." ".$kode."</strong><br/>";
endforeach;
```

The `echo` must be inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: still blank :(.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taxonomy "brand" it should be "pa_brand".

```
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'pa_brand', array('orderby'=>'name', 'fields' => 'names'));
```